# npm install vs. npm ci: node-gyp rebuild

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to build a node application within a `node-alpine` docker image. The execution of `npm install` succeeds, but `npm ci` does not succeed because of missing python. I understand that alpine does not ship python and that for building node modules the full node image is probably better suited, but I would like to understand why `npm install` does not have the same problem?

I have tested the above observation with the following steps. I started a node-alpine image with the current directory mounted into the container and by using `/bin/sh` as entry point:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app --entrypoint=/bin/sh node:10.16.0-alpine
```

and then I ran `npm install` which succeeded, followed by `npm ci` which failed. I would like to add, that the execution of `npm install` also succeeds if I delete the `node_modules` folder first.

I assumed the difference between `install` and `ci` is just in the versions that are being used, but it seems that `ci` is also trying to run `node-gyp rebuild` which fails due to the missing python environment in the alpine image, while `install` does not try to run `node-gyp rebuild` and thus succeeds.

As far as I can see this behavior is not documented anywhere in [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html)? Did I miss something?

Comment: Its possible, that this is not a general behavior of `npm ci` and that I was just observing the fallout of the following issue: https://github.com/fsevents/fsevents/issues/302. Can anyone confirm that?